# "in the context of" or "within the context of"?

Tags: idioms, prepositions

> I am going to examine this question **in** / **within** the context of the
>   epistemology of memory.

I can see that both are frequently used online. Are both equally acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

To examine something (say, a single verse in the Bible) *in context* is always a good idea--good hermeneutics too!

On the other hand, to stay *within the confines* of, say, "the epistemology of memory," is to stick to the issue at hand, which also is a good idea.

In other words, and in my opinion, the word *within* seems more suitable in your exemplar than the word *in*.

Is there a huge difference in denotation between the two words? No. On the other hand, to consider a question *in context* is to examine the circumstances surrounding the question, whereas to examine a question *within the context* is akin to bracketing the question and ignoring the surrounding circumstances, at least temporarily.

If indeed there is a difference between the two couplets, and a choice needs to be made, that difference is pretty darn subtle!